# Arabic word net synonyms c#

Tags: c#, arabic, wordnet, synonym

I am using Arabic word NET Library to get the synonyms of a given words but i get no result this is the code which i used

```
awn = new AWN(@"..\..\awn.xml", true);
List<string> words = new List<string>();
string str = awn.Get_Synset_ID_From_Word_Id("كثير");
```

But there is no result returned.
any help??

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: Have you double checked the path to the `awn.xml` file? Try a full absolute path instead of the relative path. The relative path will be from where the program is being run from. Probably `Debug\bin` folder underneath your project folder.

Comment: @AhmedMagdy I need to get the synonyms of a given word in arabic ,so i used the Arabic WordNet library. but the string str is always empty and i don't know what is the problem.

Comment: @JackHughes the path is correct i just checked it

Comment: What happens if you use a fully qualified path rather than one with `..` in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as follows

```
awn = new AWN(@"..\..\awn.xml", false);
List<string> words = new List<string>();

//get Item Id of the word
List<string> item_id = awn.Get_Item_Id_From_Name("عرض");  

//get the synonyms of the word
words = awn.Get_List_Word_Id_From_Synset_ID(item_id.First());

//get the word value for the first meaning
string s = awn.Get_Word_Value_From_Word_Id(words[0]);
```